# How to cross compile GSL library for arm-none-eabi-gcc?

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, microcontroller, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller

I need to use the GSL library in my program on LPCXpresso 4367(ARM CORTEX M4). I tried to follow the library linking procedure for LPC xpresso but the MCU linker is giving me these errors:

> MCUXpressoIDE_10.3.0_2200\workspace\test1\Debug/../src/test1.c:53: undefined reference to 'gsl_linalg_LU_decomp'
>
> MCUXpressoIDE_10.3.0_2200\workspace\test1\Debug/../src/test1.c:56: undefined reference to 'gsl_matrix_alloc'
>
> MCUXpressoIDE_10.3.0_2200\workspace\test1\Debug/../src/test1.c:57: undefined reference to 'gsl_linalg_LU_invert'

and so on for other functions as well.

I have the libgsl.a and libgslcblas.a precompiled libraries for windows which works perfectly on codeblocks on windows with GCC compiler.

I read that I need to crosscompile library for the arm-none-eabi-gcc toolchain. But can someone please provide me the procedure as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the libgsl.a and libgslcblas.a precompiled libraries for windows

Those won't do for ARM.

In order to work on another platform, these libs need to be compiled from source code with the proper compiler (and settings - Cortex-M4F requires Thumb2 instruction set).

Answer (score 0):

As the libraries are precompiled for Windows they don't work for ARM (as it is said in the other answer)

You need to cross compile the libraries first. If you install the GSL libraries following [this](https://coral.ise.lehigh.edu/jild13/2016/07/11/hello/) procedure, you only need to change the parameters in the ./config according to your platform, for example I used:

```
./config --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=/home/yourname/gsl_arm
```

Inside the .zip file with the gsl-2.5 files, there is a file called INSTALL. There you can find more details on the options for cross compiling.

Make sure to `make clean` before if you have already compiled the library for different settings. After cross-compiling the library when you run `make check` on the terminal you will probably get errors, but still it works. Continue with `make install` and you are ready to use it.

Comment: Hi @inaki.     I tried using your suggstion and was able to compile the libaray. Now I don't get the undefined reference Errors but instead now I am getting like this: `D:\Shreyas\newtest\gsl_arm\lib\libgsl.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized`
`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
`make: *** [newtest30419.axf] Error 1`

Comment: @Shreyas Are you getting the error when compiling or running? If you are compiling, are all the other settings correct for compiling for the embedded platform? If you are running, are you running on the embedded platform?

Comment: I am using the lpcxpresso IDE for programming my board. I get an error while building the program

Comment: please see this post : [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950091/why-am-i-getting-this-error-while-cross-compiling-gsl-library-for-cortex-m4)

Comment: I don't know. Try to remove all the gsl stuff and make a clean install maybe